# Assigning a variable from promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to assign a variable to one found in a controller from a promise taken from a factory, which pulls JSON data from a URL.

```
webApp = angular.module("App", []);

webApp.factory("getData", function($http) {
  var promise;
  var getData = {
    async: function() {
      if ( !promise ) {
        promise = $http.get(window.location+"/json").then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
        });
      }
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return getData;
});

webApp.controller("View", function(getData, $scope) {

  $scope.m = {}

  getData.async().then(function(m) {
    $scope.m = m;
    if ($scope.m == m) {
      console.log(true);
    }
  });

  console.log($scope.m);


});
```

Within the `.then` function, true is returned - but `$scope.m` is always returned as undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: by _returned_ I assume `console.log($scope.m);` , it's simply outside of asynchronous callback `then()`, put it inside instead

Comment: Your function getData() is async, meaning the console.log($scope.m) will be run, before the $scope.m is assigned in the callback, learn more about async

Comment: I think the duplicate given in previous comment is wrong as this question doesn't say anything about asynchronous call. A question that links Promise with asynchronous would be more appropriate.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/754119) in the duplicate explain very well about promises. It does require a bit of reading but it's worthwhile for a new developer to learn :) I've seen this type of questions asked all the time by developers who don't understand the concept of asynchronous request and that answer provide all the relevant details

Comment: @AlonEitan ooh indeed it does, I didn't check the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because promises are asynchronous methods.
That means that your `async` call is executed in parallel with the console.log() line. Therefore, at that stage of the code, the variable is not assigned.

This would print the output:

```
webApp.controller("View", function(getData, $scope) {
  $scope.m = {}

  getData.async().then(function(m) {
    $scope.m = m;
    console.log(m);
    console.log($scope.m);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates, flag for closure.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I'm slightly lost as to how I should go about using the assigned ```$scope``` variable, as it's undefined within the function I'm attempting to use.

Comment: use it within the anonymous function that is inside the .then()?

Comment: Check the link that is given as a duplicate for more details on the first comment of your question.

Comment: Did you check whether or not `m` was not `undefined` like in my answer post?